# Can I use Memento Design Pattern for JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart, memento

Is it possible to use the [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) for undo operation in JFreeChart?

If it's possible please give me some examples of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) can be used with `JFreeChart`. This typical [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern#Java_example) manages a `String`, but your `Memento` class would contain a suitable concrete implementation of your chosen `Dataset`. An instance of that dataset would be held by your `Originator`. Your `Caretaker` would then contain a `List<Originator.Memento>`. Your implementation of `Originator::set` and `Originator::restoreFromMemento` can use `setDataset()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20setdataset), to set the chart's current dataset or restore the chart to any previously saved state. For convenience, many implementations of `Dataset` implement `Cloneable`.